# How to prevent local laptop to server connection active?

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, ssh, connection

I have a windows laptop in which I have installed ubuntu subsytem. Instead of using Putty, I have installed ubuntu subsytem.

Now through my ubuntu subsytem, I ssh to the server where database is installed

```
ssh test  # logins to the test server where database is running
tmux    # I typed tmux hoping that it will keep the connection alive
```

In my local laptop, I have installed R Studio from where I run a script

Now the process is like this

1) The R studio script is ran

2) R script establishes connection to the db in server

3) data is being extracted to the local laptop

Now how can I make sure that the connection is not lost and both client (laptop) and server (db server) is active always.

1) I thought using tmux will keep the server alive (from logging out due to being idle)

2) I have changed the settings in my laptop to prevent it from sleeping or locking out

I also set up the below command in my laptop (ubuntu subsystem) `ssh/config file`

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 10
```

Like above, I tried but couldn't do any changes in server `/etc/ssh_config and /etc/sshd_config files because they were read-only`.

The script is already been running and am monitoring as well but do I have to still keep making cursor movements or am I good to leave it as is and carry on with other tasks.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34004/how-does-tcp-keepalive-work-in-ssh

Comment: In addition, should I replace $HOST with anything? or just type the command as is?

Comment: Hi @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Am learning unix. Can I check with you on one thing? I can type this `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 $HOST` on the already opened command line or do I have to open a new SSH terminal. Meaning I have to login to `ssh test` again in another terminal and then type the command suggested? can help please?